# Instantiating 2mb prefab takes long time and lags the game

Tags: unity-game-engine

When instantiate a prefab using the `Instantiate()` method, it lags my game.

I have also tried object pooling and assetBundle.

I have loaded 4 3d-Models using prefabs.

The 3d model I am instantiating has a size of `2MB`.

Comment: Is it only slow while instantiating?

Comment: Make sure you're not instantiating in the Update() method. If this would be the case it would instantiate your model every frame and that would certainly make your pc lag.

Answer (score 1):

If the prefab is that huge maybe simply you device isn't capable to render it in your desired f/s.

It is also possible that the lags don't come from the model itself but from initialization (`Awake`, `OnEnable`) calls on components attached to that object.

---

If it is only slow while instantiating you should use `Instantiate()` only once in `Awake` or `Start` and only disable/enable the objects while not needed via [`SetActive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) (somehow what object pooling does).

In case there are more scenes involved you should use [`DontDestroyOnLoad`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) in order to carry them on to other scenes.

---

You could try using something like

```c#
async Task LoadModelAsync()
{
    var assetBundle = await GetAssetBundle("www.my-server.com/myfile");
    var prefab = await assetBundle.LoadAssetAsync<GameObject>("myasset");
    GameObject.Instantiate(prefab);
    assetBundle.Unload(false);
}

async Task<AssetBundle> GetAssetBundle(string url)
{
    return (await new WWW(url)).assetBundle;
}
```

(see [How to use Async-await in Unity3d](http://www.stevevermeulen.com/index.php/2017/09/using-async-await-in-unity3d-2017/) - only that they are missing a `;` after `(await new WWW(url)).assetBundle`)

and use it like e.g.

```c#
private void Awake()
{
    InstantiateAsync();
}

async void InstantiateAsync()
{
    // Example of long running code.
    await LoadModelAsync();
}
```

(see [here for even better solutions](https://www.lucidumstudio.com/home/2017/12/5/lucidum-studio-async-code-execution-in-unity)). But keep in mind the object will not be their right away but is instantiated later.

---

Or you could get into the new [Unity Job System](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html) which seems to be even faster ([claimed here](https://jacksondunstan.com/articles/4913))